# Animated overlapping out of sight grid

Tags: wpf

How can I create a control that overlaps a window but is moveable?

I want my usercontrol to be outside of the window (invisible) and move into sight/out of sight with an animation at the press of a button. The animation part, I got. My problem is with placing the object on the edge of the screen (minus a few pixels to allow visibility of a button) and allow it to move in without changing all the other elements in the window (like it's simply going over them). I already tried leaving the grid in a "floating" state and simply moving the render transform when needed but since it's not docked to anything in particular, it goes completely out of sight when using a different screen size. I also tried making two grids with different zindex but then I end up losing access to every control on the lower index.

Answer (score 1):

Last declared elements in your xaml object will be the top most elements in your window. So you can declare an overlay grid as your last element in your window/container and do set the margin to outside of your window and then animate the margin property of the overlay grid to make it sweep inside into the window. Something like below code should help you. You can change it to suit your needs. Let me know if this is something that you are looking for.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:MultiValueConverterFromCode"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vc:ConcatStringsConverter x:Key="ConcatStringsConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="text1" Text="Hello"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="text2" Text="World"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Toggle" x:Name="toggle"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Background="Red" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0.3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="525,0,0,0"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=toggle}" Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0,0,0,0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="525,0,0,0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```